# ARMv7 CortexA9 Cache Policy - No allocate?

Tags: caching, arm, armv7, mmu

I was wondering if in a armv7 cortex-a9 it would be possible to configure cache policy in the page table entry (short descriptor format) in such a way that the cache is used only if the data already exists in the cache? A kind of write-through / "no-allocate" policy?